# How to make this nav open from right to left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried fiddling with this nav's css, but couldn't get it open from right to left.

```
.hamburger{
  $width:25px;
  $height:3px;
  width:$width;
  height:$height;
  background:white;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-$width/2;
  margin-top:-$height/2;
  transition:transform 200ms;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
transform:translate3d(110px*$i,0,0);
```

to

```
transform:translate3d(-110px*$i,0,0);
```

in the following css code , makes it open right to left :

```
.menu-open:checked~.menu-item{
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
  @for $i from 1 through $menu-items{

    &:nth-child(#{$i+2}){
      transition-duration:90ms+(100ms*$i);
      transform:translate3d(-110px*$i,0,0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop at the very end of the SCSS there's a `transform:translate3d(110px*$i,0,0);`.

```
.menu-open:checked~.menu-item{
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
  @for $i from 1 through $menu-items{

    &:nth-child(#{$i+2}){
      transition-duration:90ms+(100ms*$i);
      transform:translate3d(110px*$i,0,0);
    }
  }
}
```

Changing this to a negative value, `-110px` will make the animation appear right to left. However, you need to update some other CSS as well which I'll leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -110px to turn to the right

```
 .menu-open:checked~.menu-item{
      transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
      @for $i from 1 through $menu-items{

        &:nth-child(#{$i+2}){
          transition-duration:90ms+(100ms*$i);
          transform:translate3d(-110px*$i,0,0);
        }
      }
    }
```

And remove the svg.

https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/BVmKaO